# Finding Invalid AppIIDs by Batch

Tags: android, firebase

I have optimised message sending via `Firebase` by using the Batch APIs which allow me to send to 100 AppIIDs at once.  However, I need to know which AppIIDs are no longer valid in order that I can revert to sending via `SMTP` or SMS message.

The `SendAllAsync` and `SendMulticastAsync` APIs always return success for `AppIIDs` even if the associated App has been uninstalled.

The only way I have found to check, is to poll each `AppIID's` details in turn, using

https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/[AppIID]?details=true

Which tells me if a single `AppIID` is still live.  However this is very time consuming.  For 100 AppIIDs this takes around 70s.

Is there a better way of doing this, one which will allow me to get this information in a single batch call ?

Comment: What do you mean by AppIIDs? Push Notifications (i.e. FCM's)?

Comment: This is the registration ID which the App receives from Firebase when it initialises.  By passing this to the server, it allows us to push notifications to any chosen client. I think the accronym is derived from App Instance ID.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/